# calculating age and turning it into a variable

Tags: javascript, validation, date

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

         var BDyear = document.getElementById("BDyear").value
         var BDmonth = document.getElementById("BDmonth").value
         var BDday = document.getElementById("BDday").value
         var BDstate = false
         var BDcheck = true
         var Cdate = new Date()
         var Cyear = Cdate.getFullYear()

// sectioning age calulation into months with 28 30 and 31 days
if ((BDyear <= Cyear && BDyear >= 1920) && (BDmonth <= 12 && BDmonth >= 1) && (BDday <= 28 && BDday >= 1) && BDmonth == 2) {
                 document.getElementById("bderror").style.display = "none"
                 //
                 // Age calculation place holder
                 //
                 if (age < 13) {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'inline'
                     BDstate = false
                 }
                 else {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'none'
                     BDstate = true
                 }


             }

             if ((BDyear <= Cyear && BDyear >= 1920) && (BDmonth <= 12 && BDmonth >= 1) && (BDday <= 31 && BDday >= 1) && (BDmonth == 1 || BDmonth == 3 || BDmonth == 5 || BDmonth == 7 || BDmonth == 8 || BDmonth == 10 || BDmonth == 12)) {
                 document.getElementById("bderror").style.display = "none"
                 //
                 // Age calculation place holder
                 //
                 if (age < 13) {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'inline'
                     BDstate = false
                 }
                 else {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'none'
                     BDstate = true
                 }
             }


             if ((BDyear <= Cyear && BDyear >= 1920) && (BDmonth <= 12 && BDmonth >= 1) && (BDday <= 30 && BDday >= 1) && (BDmonth == 2 || BDmonth == 4 || BDmonth == 6 || BDmonth == 9 || BDmonth == 11)) {
                 document.getElementById("bderror").style.display = "none"
                 //
                 // Age calculation place holder
                 //
                 if (age < 13) {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'inline'
                     BDstate = false
                 }
                 else {
                     document.getElementById("bderroryoung").display = 'none'
                     BDstate = true
                 }

             }
         }
 </script>

 <input class="text" id="BDyear" maxlength="4" style="width:8%" />&nbsp/&nbsp<input class="text" id="BDmonth" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" />&nbsp/&nbsp<input class="text" id="BDday" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" /><br />
                     <p id="bderror" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none"> תאריך לידה לא תקין</p>
                     <p id="bderroryoung" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none"> חובה להיות מעל גיל 13</p>
```

I looked up a lot of ways to calculate the age from birth-date and they all end up with the use of "return", while i'm a complete rookie and working on my school project in my first year of programming i struggle with all these arguments and stuff...

Can anyone show me according to my code how can i insert the calculation process to be finalized as a numeric valued variable?

Note: this is a small portion of the code and all the objects are defined properly. the birth date syntax is DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see many examples using a "return" goes along with the advantages of structuring your code into functions.  This would be a good next step for you in learning to program.  Functions will allow you to create chunks of code that are reusable and also easier to read and debug.

To answer your question:

```
var BDyear = document.getElementById("BDyear").value
var BDmonth = document.getElementById("BDmonth").value
var BDday = document.getElementById("BDday").value

// create a new date object based on your input
var BDdate  = new Date(BDyear, BDmonth, BDday);

// get today's date
var Today = new Date();

// getTime returns time in milliseconds
var DateDiff = Today.getTime() -BDdate.getTime();

// convert milliseconds to years and return the floor

// milliseconds in a year
var YearMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

// here is your variable with the age
var Age = Math.floor(DateDiff / YearMilliseconds);
```

UPDATE

The above doesn't take leap year into account [even if we changed days in a year to 365.242199].  It feels better because we are doing some fun math but we could forget about special cases if we just compared the month & day like so:

```
var BDdate  = new Date(BDyear, BDmonth, BDday);

// get today's date
var Today = new Date();

// get current month.  adjust by one so it is using same scale as user input [getMonth() returns 0-11);
var TodayMonth = Today.getMonth() + 1;

// difference in years
var Age = Today.getFullYear() -BDdate.getFullYear();

// adjust for month/day
// if the birth month was greater than today, subtract a year
// if the birth month is the same as this one, we need to compare the actual day
if (BDmonth > TodayMonth || (BDmonth === TodayMonth && BDday > Today.getDate())) {
    // oops, it's not our birthday yet, so subtract a year
    Age = Age - 1;    
}

// Age is ready to use
```

[see w3schools for more info on the Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: This actually pretty great. there are so many ways to do stuff like this but this one i think will actually fit into my function without the need for any other functions and more struggle. also this means i can delete the sectioning for months with certain amount of days, correct?

Comment: I will most likely see your comment in the morning tomorrow     (gettin' late), but i will most definitely try your answer - it looks simple and easy to understand and insert into my code. a thousand times thank you, sir! you have helped me a lot!

Comment: thanks.  i wanted to give you something that fit within your existing code and programming level.  I really do want to encourage you to learn about functions, etc though when the time is right.  Javascript and programming are awesome things to get into and you should move at the pace your are comfortable with and build on your existing knowledge.


you can ditch the sectioning for months and days but one thing I omitted is taking into account leap year.  more on that in a moment...

Comment: The actual function doesn't show up in the code i posted. So i actualy do use functions,  but what i wonder is if you can get different returns out of the same function just in different parts. Otherwise i'm gonna have to break each validation part for every input to different functions and them call them all at once

Answer (score 0):

You want a function that returns the right value. e.g.:

```
function returnAge(day, month, year) {
    var theAge;

    // ... do calculations and set theAge

    return theAge;
}
```

Then you want to call that function and put the value it returns into variable and work with that.

```
var age = returnAge(BDday, BDmonth, BDyear)
if (age < 13) { /* do something */ }
else { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Okay, so say i return it to some html input or something and make it invisible and then in the next line i will take the value of the input, will it be the actual age extracted from the birth date? or is it possible doing without all that process

Comment: I was assuming you want to show the *answer* inside an input element with id "BDdayanswer". If you make such an input element, the answer will appear there with the code I shared.

Comment: I actually wanted to it use to restrict registration to below 13 years old users. after the stage that i got the age i wanted to see if it's below 13 and then cancel the registration process with an error

Comment: Ah... i think i get it now. I still have to learn how to use the return thing though , but this makes the things clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a date library like date.js. You are doing alot of manual date calculations that would not be nesecerary with Date.js.

http://www.datejs.com/

You can use it like this:

```
var BDyear = document.getElementById("BDyear").value;
var BDmonth = document.getElementById("BDmonth").value;
var BDday = document.getElementById("BDday").value;

var birthDate = new Date(BDday + '/' + BDmonth + '/' +  BDyear);

if (birthDate != null) {
    var age = calculateAge(birthDate);
}


function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); 
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Comment: Can you actually break it down and explain what each line does? (except the obvious) As i mentioned i'm a complete rookie and i'm actually trying to understand what am i doing